# Hangul does not appear in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use ***String*** in C# in script, but Korean is displayed in console, but Korean is broken in inspector. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Nothing. That's just a basic text display. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

괜찮아요. Unity가 해당 텍스트 필드에 한국어를 표시하는 방법을 모르기 때문입니다. 하지만 만들고 있는 실제 앱에서는 제대로 작동합니다.